# Find the simple closed form of summation from $k=0$ to $N$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am studying for my discrete mathematics class and I came across a question asking to find the simple closed form of the summation below. I know that $\binom{N}k = \frac{N!}{N!(N-k)!}$ but I am unsure how to use that to find the closed form. I cannot find a simple answer on what a simple closed form is.

$$\sum_{k=0}^N (k^2-k) \binom{N}k $$

Thank you

Comment: Consider the second derivative of $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k} x^k = (1+x)^N$

Comment: and that $k^2-k = k(k-1)$

Comment: So, once I foil them together, is that my final answer? I have not really been able to find a simple explanation of a simple closed form.

Comment: @roberthayek Yes differentiate the LHS twice and evaluate at $1$.  You should get your question.  Then differentiate the RHS twice and evaluate at $1$.  As the LHS equals the RHS, you get the same thing, but in closed form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Simple math show that $k\binom{N}{k}=N\binom{N-1}{k-1}$, so
   $$\sum_{k=1}^Nk\binom{N}{k}=N\sum_{k=1}^N\binom{N-1}{k-1}=N2^{N-1}$$
2. Using the identity at 1.
   \begin{eqnarray}
   k^2\binom{N}{k}=Nk\binom{N-1}{k-1}&=&N(k-1)\binom{N-1}{k-1}+N\binom{N-1}{k-1}\\
   &=&N(N-1)\binom{N-2}{k-2}+N\binom{N-1}{k-1}
   \end{eqnarray}
   So taking sum over $k^2\binom{N}{k}$ we get
   $$\sum_{k=1}^Nk^2\binom{N}{k}=N(N-1)\sum_{k=2}^N\binom{N-2}{k-2}+N\sum_{k=1}^N\binom{N-1}{k-1}=2^{N-2}N(N+1)$$
   Then the closed form is $2^{N-2}N(N-1)$

Comment: There's a typo at the last sentence; the $(N-1)$ term should be $(N+1)$ instead.

Comment: @VTand $2^{N-2}N(N+1)-N2^{N-1}=2^{N-2}(N^2+N-2N)=2^{N-2}(N^2-N)$

Comment: My bad, I thought the question was asking for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \binom{N}{k}$.